# Install phone version of app on tablet instead of tablet version?

Tags: applications, installation, tablet

Is there any way to force an app to install its phone version rather than the tablet version on a device? The particular app I have in mind is Microsoft Edge, whose tablet version is missing several features found on the phone version.

Comment: If there are really two different app versions then it depends on the developer what app version is available for what devices in Google Play Store. If the phone version is not available then you can only get it from third party sites like apkmirror.

Comment: According to [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/microsoft-corporation/microsoft-edge/#variants), there is only 1 dpi variant (nodpi) of Microsoft Edge. This might mean that the app only changes its behavior when it detects the device as a "tablet", e.g. [smallest width](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/202151/44325), DPI, etc.